Epsilon-delta proof that $\frac{1-\cos x\cos y}{x^2+y^2}\to\frac12$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

Prove that $f(x,y):=\frac{1-\cos x\cos y}{x^2+y^2}\to\frac12$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

I can't find proper $δ$ to prove this limit.
Is this because I need to use Taylor's expansion or something else? I tried
$$\begin{align}
2(1-\cos x \cos y)&= 1- \cos(x+y) +1 - \cos(x-y)\\&= 2 \sin^2 \left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)+ 2 \sin^2 \left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right).
\end{align}$$

You are on a right track and don't need Taylor. Only $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t}t=1$.

or,  as the series for cosine is strictly alternating   decreasing  for real $t$ between $-1$  and $1,$  we get $ 1 - \frac{t^2}{2} \leq \cos t \leq 1 - \frac{t^2}{2} +  \frac{t^4}{24}.$   Write this out for $t=x$  and separately for $t = y,$  this gives pleasant bounds on your ratio.

Letting $u,v=\frac{x\pm y}2$, my hint concludes your attempt: $\lim_{(u,v)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin^2u+\sin^2v}{u^2+v^2}=1$.
